# Trying to pass some output of lsof -Pi to geoiplookup

Tags: bash, lsof

Looking for a way to pass the second column of output to geoiplookup, ideally on the same line, but not necessarily. This is the best I can muster. It's usable, but the geoiplookup results are unfortunately below the list of connections. I wanted more integrated results. If anyone can suggest improvements, they would be welcome.

```
ns () {
  echo ""
  while sleep 1; do
    lsof -Pi |
    grep ESTABLISHED |
    sed "s/[^:]*$//g" |
    sed "s/^[^:]*//g" |
    sed "s/://g" |
    sed "s/->/\t/g" |
    grep -v localdomain$ |
    tee >(for x in `grep -o "\S*$"`; do geoiplookup $x | sed "s/GeoIP.*: /\t/g"; done)
  done
}
```

The results currently look something like this:

```
<Port>    <URL or IP if no reverse available #1>
<Port>    <URL or IP if no reverse available #2>
    <geoiplookup trimmed result #1>
    <geoiplookup trimmed result #2>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received an excellent answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/436154/trying-to-pass-some-output-of-lsof-pi-to-geoiplookup/436967#436967).